# How do I use the prefix 'de-' correctly?

Tags: meaning, prefixes, resources

Is there a dictionary dedicated to word prefixes? I'd like to know more about *de-*, but there's no uniform meaning; for example, in *demystify* it signifies a reverse action, while in *delimit* it's a positive meaning, like *set*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a dictionary dedicated solely to prefixes. But you can find some common prefixes and their definitions in normal dictionaries. E.g. definitions of the prefix *de-* may be found in [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/de-prefix):

> 1. away from, off: debar, derail
> 2. down: degrade
> 3. wholly, entirely: defunct
> 4. reverse the action of; undo: defrost, decode

Edit: On the second thought, there are some. You can try searching for "Merriam-Webster's a Dictionary of Prefixes, Suffixes, And Combining Forms". I'm not sure if we're allowed to post links to resources, where you can actually download one though, else I'd give you one.

Comment: I'm sure there isn't a "dictionary" dedicated to *suffixes*, but there is Michael Quinion's excellent [Ologies and Isms](http://www.affixes.org/), which covers all "affixes" *(prefixes, suffixes,* and *infixes)*. I think he even includes *bloody* as an "intensifying infix" in the expression **abso-bloody-lutely**.

Comment: Wiktionary covers prefixes [just fine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de-). So does [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0).